# Storing ArrayList with custom object

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to save ArrayList with a custom object in it. Problem is that the ArrayList is in my singleton. My singleton "Choices" holds `ArrayList<Choice> list;` and the "Choice" has 4 different types of variables.

I don't know how to access my ArrayList from my activity because the below code didn't work. `getMyList()` method returns list.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(Choices.getInstance().getMyList());
    editor.putString("list", json);
    editor.commit();
```

When I'm retrieving the list I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
    String json = prefs.getString("list", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<Choice>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<Choice> savedList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Any help or suggestions would help a lot.

Comment: `Choices.getInstance().getMyList()` may be empty. Have you added any data in it??

Comment: I have done this, choice = new Choice(time, number, number2); and then getInstance().addToList(choice);

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Comment: This happens when I'm trying to load the data. Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myApp.Choice cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList. When I'm retrieving data I tried this Choices.getInstance().addSavedData(savedList); and Choices.getInstance().getMyList().addAll(savedList); I'm not sure how to load saveList properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrieving code change 
 
`Type type = new TypeToken<Choice>() {}.getType();`
 
to
 `Type type = new TypeToken<List<Choice>>() {}.getType()`;
as you need to parse though a list of your custom object.

Answer (score 0):

How about this while retrieval :

```
String json = prefs.getString("list", "");
ArrayList<Choice> savedList = (ArrayList<Choice>) jsonToList(json,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<Choice>>() {
                    }.getType());

public static Object jsonToList(String jsonString, Type type) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
    }
```